# Outputting contents of database mysqli

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, connection

Hi I know this is a little general but its something I cant seem to work out by reading online.

Im trying to connnect to a database using php / mysqli using a wamp server and a database which is local host on php admin.

No matter what I try i keep getting the error  Warning: `mysqli_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, boolean given when i try to output the contents of the database.

the code im using is:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost");
    if ($con == true)
    {
        echo "Database connection established";
    }
    else 
    {
        die("Unable to connect to database");
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['login'];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not wrote the full query.

Comment: originally i was trying SELECT * FROM login (which is a table) but as it iddnt work i shortened it to see if it worked that way

Comment: your database connection si wrong. and then what is login? @user3500964

Comment: @user3500964 this will not work in this way, the result set of the query execution is passes to the `mysqli_fetch_array` but the query was not executing that's why it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

I will be good if you have a look at the standard `mysqli_connect` [**here**][1]
I will dont seem to see where you have selected any data base before attempting to dump it contents.

```
<?php
//set up basic connection :
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","passw","db") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

Following this basic standard will also help you know where prob is.
[1]: https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect

Answer (score 0):

you have to select from table . or mysqli dont know what table are you selecting from.

change this

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *");
```

to

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name ");
```

- `table_name` is the name of your table

and your connection is tottally wrong.

use this

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database_name");
```

you have to learn here [how to connect and use mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect)